# What does 0.0.0.0:* mean in netstat?

Tags: udp, netstat

Could anyone explain the following output of `netstat -plunt`?

```
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:58262           0.0.0.0:*  1163/avahi-daemon:    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:17500           0.0.0.0:*  3779/dropbox:u    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*  1163/avahi-daemon:
```

What does 0.0.0.0:* mean? Are all the ports being listened or something else?

Comment: possible cross site duplicate of: http://superuser.com/questions/386436/the-meaning-of-port-0-in-netstat-output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The column after local address is "Foreign Address" - as these are UDP ports, and listening ports, there is no foreign address so a wildcard is shown.

I'm not sure if this would show the other end(s) if packets had been received as UDP is a connectionless protocol. Also as one-many comms is allowed a single foreign address could be misleading. So it may ALWAYS show the wildcard for udp.

Answer (score 3):

If it says 0.0.0.0 on the Local Address column, it means that port is listening on all 'network interfaces' (i.e. your computer, your modem(s) and your network card(s))